# Can't connect to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, windows-server-2008

I'm currently developing a web application using asp.net c#. I got a server where I today was 
going to publish my website and its database. Its a server that runs Windows Server 2008 R2.

But I have one issue:

My website doesn't seem to get access to the database. If I run the website from another computer on my local network I can access the server's database, BUT I can't when I run the website from the same server where the database is. This is really weird. I hope someone can help.

I just get an error that says, it can't access the database.

The most weird of all is that I'm using the same connection string on both computers, but it still doesn't work. Are there maybe some sort of settings in Windows Server 2008?

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=AXELS;Initial Catalog=Sailor;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=saab123" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Check actual exception message.

Comment: Does it work on the server if you change the server name in your connection string to `localhost` or `.`?

Comment: I hope you're **not really** using the `sa` account to log in to your SQL Server in production - right???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the connection works on one machine and not on another, I'd guess you have an issue with a firewall or similar - but it will be hard to tell until we see the actual error message. Until then, there are a few things you might want to do:

- If it appears as if the connection has to time out before you get the error, it indicates a connectivity problem. Do you have a firewall between the two servers? Does the database server have a firewall that explicitly lets your machine (or internal) machines get through, but hasn't been setup to let the webserver get through? You have to make sure that port 1433 is open on the server.
- Are there other sites on the webserver that can connect to the database?
- If you have console access to the server, try to set up an ODBC from the server to the database - usually in Control Panel -> Data Sources (ODBC). If you set up a connection with the same DB Server, username and password and test the connection, you might get some pointers to what is wrong.

If the above doesn't provide you with an answer, I'd try to go through the steps described here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

And if that fails, take a look at this - which is apparently only valid when you get `SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26`

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

Comment: I did an test connection in the ODBC and that worked haha, but my website connection to the database won't work...

Comment: And where exactly does your connection fail? When you open the connection, try to do something with it,...?

Comment: When im going to open the connection

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Can we continue this in the chat?

Comment: Is the database server newly configured/installed? Are you aware of any other websites connecting to it? Have you checked the first of my points in the answer? (Ie. checking for a firewall on the DB-server itself.)

Comment: Yea! But i don't see how a firewall could trouble when im trying to connect to it from the same computer, when it works from another computer locally. But yes, the firewall is even turned off

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5969/discussion-between-anders-up-and-parek)

Comment: the last link is broken

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a permission problem.
You need to show us your connection string so we can see how exactly you try to connect to your database.

For example, if you are using Windows authentication, maybe your app runs under different accounts on both machines - and the account on the other computers **has** permission to access the database, but the account on the database server has not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the if the protocols you are using are enabled on the SQL Server e.g.

C:\Windows\System32\cliconfg.exe  -- 64 bit version

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cliconfg.exe  -- 32 bit version

or check SQL Server Configuration Manager 'SQL Server Native Client *' tabs.

Comment: Remember that i can connect from my other local pc to the database, so i don't think theres some sort of protocol problem

Comment: If the protocol is not enabled on the SQL Server you cannot use that protocol locally. cliconfg is local to each machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is only applicable if you do not use Windows Authentication, else read the post about priviliges from Christian Specht - in this case I agree.

The fact that you can connect from another PC on the network means that all you database settings, user accounts and permissions are probably set up correct.

It seems there might be a issue with the way the server resolves localhost, as it will try to resolve the Data Source to localhost because AXELS = localhost on that machine.

Have a look at your hosts file and see if there's any funny pointers except for the default.

Located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

There should be an entry: 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using Windows Authentication? In that case, your website might be using the ASPNET user when its on the server itself which does not grant it access to the DB. That would explain why you can connect remotely, because you are either using a network account or a different service account which does have access.